# vCenter 7.0 behind nginx reverse proxy issue

Tags: nginx, vmware-vcenter

Don't judge, I need this for my lab, I'll never put that in production...

The following configuration was from another guy on the internet (pigsmud) so unfortunately, I'm not understanding a lot of things here. Also his website just vanished so I'll not be able to discuss the topic with him any further (which I did for the 6.7)

That was my working 6.X working for vCenter 6.7:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        # ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key are required
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myletsencryptdomain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myletsencryptdomain/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        # removed DH params as my ssl-params.conf specifies to only use ECDHE key exchange.

        server_name fqdn.extern;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
                proxy_pass https://vcenter.ip; # esxi IP Address
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
                #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
                }

                location /websso/SAML2 {
                proxy_set_header Host fqdn.local; # your actual vcenter's hostname
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
                proxy_pass https://vcenter.ip; # esxi IP Address
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
                #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
        }
  }
```

This was my previous (non working) 7.0 configuration. The section "location /ui/login" was necessary to get to the login mask, otherwise, I was just getting an error. I added then /ui/saml/websso/sso but it wasn't working:

```
# vCenter special configuration
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myletsencryptdomain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myletsencryptdomain/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        server_name fqdn.extern;

                location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
                proxy_pass https://vcenter.ip; # esxi IP Address
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
                #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
                }

                location /websso/SAML2 {
                proxy_set_header Host fqdn.local; # your actual vcenter's hostname
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
                proxy_pass https://vcenter.ip; # esxi IP Address
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
                #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
                }

                location /ui/login {
                proxy_set_header Host fqdn.local; # your actual vcenter's hostname
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
                proxy_pass https://vcenter.ip; # esxi IP Address
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
                #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
                }

                location /ui/saml/websso/sso {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                #proxy_set_header Host fqdn.local; # your actual vcenter's hostname
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
                proxy_pass https://vcenter.ip; # esxi IP Address
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;
                proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
                proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
                #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
                }
    }
```

Then, I was able to simplify the config but I still get the exact same result (but with a WAAAYYY shorter config)

I've removed all the certificates parameters because I'm using a certificate with several names, so I could move that to http section.

I've tried several combinations so it is still very unclear which line is doing what...

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name fqdn.extern;

            location / {
            #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
            proxy_pass https://fqdn.local/;
            #proxy_pass https://vcenter.ip; # esxi IP Address
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_buffering off;
            #client_max_body_size 0;
            #proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
            proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
            #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
            }
}
```

I'm trying now to understand why I'm still getting redirected to the local server when I'm trying to login to the vcenter. What works so far:

https://fqdn.extern/ --> https://fqdn.extern/ui --> https://fqdn.extern/websso/SAML2/SSO/

But when I press login button (on the websso/SAML2/SSO/ page), I get https://fqdn.local/ui/saml/websso/sso and of course, I'm not getting any further. Right after, it is supposed to go back to /ui/ alone (this is what I'm seeing when logging in locally)

At this point, if I try to get back at the root of the external URL, it seems I'm logged-in because it goes straight back to /ui/saml/websso/sso, so a part of the proxying worked, but I still can't get access to the vcenter.

Any idea so far?

(and if I can get a small crash course, I'll be more than happy!!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just need add two parameter
proxy_set_header Host "fqdn.local";
and
sub_filter "fqdn.local" "fqdn.extern";

It's work for vCenter 7.0

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key are required
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myletsencryptdomain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myletsencryptdomain/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    # removed DH params as my ssl-params.conf specifies to only use ECDHE key exchange.

    server_name fqdn.extern;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host "fqdn.local";
            proxy_set_header Origin "fqdn.local";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
            proxy_pass https://fqdn.local; # esxi IP Address
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_buffering off;
            client_max_body_size 0;
            proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
            proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
            #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
            }

    location /websso/SAML2 {
            sub_filter "fqdn.local" "fqdn.extern";
            proxy_set_header Host fqdn.local; # your actual vcenter's hostname
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_ssl_verify off; # No need on isolated LAN
            proxy_pass https://fqdn.local; # esxi IP Address
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_buffering off;
            client_max_body_size 0;
            proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
            proxy_redirect https://fqdn.local/ https://fqdn.extern/; # read comment below
            #replace vcenter-hostname with your actual vcenter's hostname, and esxi with your nginx's server_name.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works! :-)

(I'll be happy of you can quickly explain...)

Comment: `proxy_set_header Origin "fqdn.local";` is what is also needed to allow real time updates and remote console availablity

Answer (score 0):

I got this config working with vCenter 8.0 and the task viewer is also working:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host vcenter_hostname;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass https://vcenter_hostname;
}
location /ui/app-fabric/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass https://vcenter_hostname;
}
location /websso/SAML2 {
    sub_filter "vcenter_hostname" "vcenter_reverse_proxy_hostname";
    proxy_set_header Host vcenter_hostname;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    proxy_pass https://vcenter_hostname;
}
```